# How to open vscode terminal with non-root user?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode in window11 wsl2. When I type `code .` in my terminal and it opens.
But the internal terminal user is always "root".

Because of this problem, ssh run with a config file that located in '/root/.ssh/config'

I want to open vscode with local user.

[image]

Comment: in the shell where you run `code .`, do you run that command as the root user?

Comment: no... I logged in common user.